# What is the time complexity of learninig phase of Hopfield neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, data-mining, time-complexity

It really intrigues me what is the time complexity of learning phase of Hopfield neural network, how it depends of the number of training examples and number of attributes?

[Source code of Hopfield neural network](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577461-hopfield-artificial-neural-network/)

Can we say that time complexity of Hopfield neural network quadratically depend on the number of training examples or quadratically depend on the number of attributes?

Thank you!